# Каким образом я могу получить текущего пользователя

Tags: django, sqlite3, django-model

Необходимо сохранить данные с формы в БД, при этом в представлении, есть поле `owner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="bid")`, то есть нужно указать текущего пользователя, я пытаюсь это сделать задав значение **default**, но как мне получить ID текущего пользователя. Пользователь создан таким образом с помощью **AbstractUser**: `class User(AbstractUser)`

Models.py

```
class Auctions(models.Model):
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="bid", default=f"{**ID текущего пользователя**}")
   product_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
   product_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   product_bid = models.IntegerField()
   image_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Str")
   def __str__(self):
      return f"Product name: {self.product_name}, {self.product_description}, current bid:{self.product_bid}"
```

Views.py

```
def create_auction(request):
error = ""
if request.method== "POST":
    form = AuctionsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else: 
        error = "Valid data"
form = AuctionsForm
data = {
    "form":form
}
return render(request, "auctions/new_auction.html", data)
```

Возможно есть метод лучше чем этот для сохранения данных, буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create_auction(request):
    if request.method== "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated:
        form = AuctionsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            candidate = form.save(commit=False) # это нужно чтобы объект в модели создался, но зависимости пока не проверялись 
            candidate.owner = request.user 
            candidate.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
```

В шаблоне пользователя отображать не надо, но надо поле добавить скрытым

```
{{ form.owner.as_hidden }}
```

Comment: Tatarincev, Спасибо, работает

Comment: поставьте отметку что ваша проблема решена